# R using a higher order function to give all rows in a matrix an additional identity

Tags: r, attributes, higher-order-functions

In R, I have a matrix with rownames and I would like to give each row an additional tag/attribute. That is, based on some criteria that I test for, I would like to use the apply or (some higher-order function) to iterate through all rows in the matrix and give each row an additional tag/attribute (what is the correct R vocabulary word here?). For example I would like to tag each row in my matrix as either "red", "blue", or "white".

1. How can I tag each row in a matrix "Red", "blue", or "white" with a higher-order function?
2. How can I do 1. without higher-order functions and just loops?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to turn this into a dataframe and add a new "color"/tag variable to it?

Comment: The best way to "tag" each row will depend strongly on how you want to _use_ them, and you haven't given any guidance on that. As mentioned, using a data frame is one option, or you could simply add an attribute that is a vector of tags.

Comment: Either way sounds fine. What is most important to me is how I apply the test. I'll add an edit.

Comment: The point is that you have some ultimate purpose in mind, and unless adding rowtags speeds up or simplifies the processing, why bother in the first place?  If you tell us *why* you are filtering rows, we can suggest an approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two implementations come to mind.
 (1)  Use a data.frame
 (2)  Maintain the matrix (faster) and have a sepeartet vector for indexing

#### (1) using a data.frame

```
 myDF <- as.data.frame(myMatrix)

 myDF$color <- apply(myDF, 1, ColoringFunction)

 # grab all the "red" ones
 myDF[myDF$color=="red", ]
```

#### (2) using a indexing vector

```
 myMatrix # remains a matrix

 ColorIndex <- apply(myMatrix, 1, ColoringFunction)

 # grab all the "red" ones
 myMatrix[ColorIndex =="red", ]

 # to initialize the vector to a given value use: 
 ColorIndex <- rep("green", nrow(myMatrix))
```

*Where `myMatrix` is your original data, and `ColoringFunction(<matrix row>)` is the function you are using to determine color assignment.*

Comment: How would I set every row to a single color?

Comment: How would method (2) become a vector where every entry is "red" such that the number of entries is the same as the number of rows in myMatrix?

Comment: Your edit works! But, in your answer in method 2 you write `myDF` where you should mean myMatrix. Also, I would like to be able to access this ColorIndex by myMatrix[5,]$ColorIndex. It doesnt have to be the $ operator. I just care that it works like the dot operator in Java or C++ (properties/attributes). Does your method supply this?

Comment: thanks for catching the typo, I edited the answer. I'm not sure what you mean by `myMatrix[5,]$ColorIndex`.  What are you trying to do.  Also, if the answer to this is lengthy, please consider opening a new questions as answering questions in the comments becomes cumbersome.

Comment: The point to the `ColorIndex` is that its elements match the rows of the matrix.  Thus, if you want to access the 5th row or the 5th element, you would use  `myMat[5, ]` and `ColorIndex[5]`.   If you want to match which rows of myMat have a correspodning color, you can use `myMat[ColorIndex=="green", ]`

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` might be useful here. Example:

```
x <- data.table(A = 1:5, B = jitter(1:5))
x[, Index := ifelse(A < 3, 'red', 'blue')]
setkey(x, Index)
```

As an example I'm tagging anything in the first column less than 3 as `red`, everything else as `blue`... but I'm sure you'll have your own criteria. Once the key has been set, you can retrieve rows under that index/tag. E.g.:

```
x['blue']
```

`data.table` will do this extremely quickly.

---

Or here's a more custom way of going about it. Have a function that takes your data, the indexing/tagging method and returns a way of retrieving rows under a certain tag:

```
tagger <- function(df, setIndex) {
  indexer <- apply(df, 1, setIndex)
  function(index) df[indexer == index, ]
}
```

You can feed any method of tagging into this. I'll use the same method as in the `data.table` example, and the same data (data frame `x`).

```
x <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = jitter(1:5))
setIndex <- function(xx) ifelse(xx$A < 3, 'red', 'blue')
getTag <- tagger(x, setIndex)
```

Now you can retrieve rows by tag:

```
getTag('red')
```

---

If you want to do something more sophisticated try using a class.

```
indexer <- setRefClass('indexer', 
  fields = list(df = 'data.frame', indexing = 'character', setIndex = 'function'),
  methods = list(

  # Initialise.
  initialize = function(df, setIndex, ...) {
    initIndex = apply(df, 1, setIndex)
    callSuper(df = df, indexing = initIndex, setIndex = setIndex, ...)
  },

  # Apply new indxing function.
  newIndex = function(setIndex) .self$setIndex <- setIndex, 

  # Apply an indexing function.
  performIndexing = function() .self$indexing <- apply(df, 1, setIndex),

  # Reapply the index function.
  reIndex = function() performIndexing(),

  # Get a row by tag.
  getTag = function(index) df[indexing == index, ],

  # View the indexes for each row.
  viewIndex = function() data.frame(df, Tag = indexing),

  # Change a tag for some row. 
  changeIndexAt = function(at, new_index) .self$indexing[at] <- new_index
  )
)


# Sample data.
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = jitter(1:5))

# Create.
i <- indexer$new(df = df, setIndex = setIndex)

# Get rows tagged as red.
i$getTag('red')

# Reapply row tagging.
i$reIndex()

# Change the tag for the second row.
i$changeIndexAt(2, 'green')
i$getTag('green')

# View the tags.
i$viewIndex()
```

And so on.